# Why are my exceptions rendered differently after versions update?

Tags: truffle, testing, ganache, revert

**I don't remember the previous versions I was using** but I remember upgrading because I hoped to have a local test network (via Ganache) supporting EIP-1559. My versions are:

```
Truffle v5.11.5 (core: 5.11.5)
Ganache v7.9.1
Solidity - 0.8.10 (solc-js)
Node v18.18.0
Web3.js v1.10.0
```

But there's something weird here:

- Tests that were expected to succeed (and designed in that way) have no problem.
- For some tests that expect a revert (and were also designed in that way) I had to change the captured revert message.
- But there are a lot of tests that expect a failure (using expectRevert) that expected certain text to exist, and now I get a big payload with no description instead.

For example, take this code which is part of a well-designed test:

```
          await expectRevert(
            payments.executePaymentOrderConfirmationCall(
              obj, web3, accounts[9], economy.address, economy.abi, realWorldPaymentsPlugin.address,
              realWorldPaymentsPlugin.abi, false, {amount: gasAmount}
            ),
            "RealWorldPaymentsPlugin: payment already processed"
          );
```

I remember this test (and many others like this one) to pass (i.e. the operation I made in that exact code moment indeed belonged to a payment already being processed). But for this exception I get this message instead:

```
      Wrong kind of exception received
      + expected - actual

      -Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
      -{
      -  "transactionHash": "0x94fde2832f19dd6aef96c262982cd0a3b916b023206c44d8344894d7475e4d60",
      -  "transactionIndex": 0,
      -  "blockNumber": 59,
      -  "blockHash": "0xc19bc86efddf4d43957c72cbce27c89053e4347e0d5ddc3b516970a8cf9505c9",
      -  "from": "0x5aeda56215b167893e80b4fe645ba6d5bab767de",
      -  "to": "0xb9b7e0cb2edf5ea031c8b297a5a1fa20379b6a0a",
      -  "cumulativeGasUsed": 65459,
      -  "gasUsed": 65459,
      -  "contractAddress": null,
      -  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      -  "status": false,
      -  "effectiveGasPrice": 2505438371,
      -  "type": "0x2",
      -  "events": {}
      -}
      +RealWorldPaymentsPlugin: payment already processed
```

I ensured I'm giving a lot of gas (and I believe this should not be a problem, since this was working before), literally more than 100000 units. What am I doing wrong?

- Is a matter of library versions? Are there bugs here? (again: this only happens when capturing these exceptions)
- Is because this network now supports 1559 and I'm forgetting something?
- How do I retrieve or understand a meaningful description out of that payload?

Comment: There isn't enough information to determine the exact problem. Like you say it could be a version issue, sometimes solc default evm version changes cause similar issues. You will need to provide the contracts and test used.